# Pontiac Grand Prix Rpm dropping to soon

Tags: engine, pontiac, grand-prix

I drive a 05 Pontiac Grand Prix  when I press the gas the RPM go up but then drop while I am still pressing the gas pedal.   RPM. drops but I am still accelerating  .  Doesn't do it every time.

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something here but this sounds very much like the normal process of an automatic gearbox shifting up through the gears while you accelerate.

For engine revs to drop while roadspeed continues to increase shifting to a higher gear is pretty much the only explanation (although I suppose shifting to neutral while going down a steep hill might count if I were being pedantic)